# Multiple source control with indexOf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexof

This my first array:

```
kaos = [1,2,6,9,15,18,21];
```

And this is second array:

```
zeus = [1,3];
```

I want search search zeus in kaos on `indexOf(1, 3)`

**this is working:**

```
kaos.indexOf(1)!=-1;
```

**but this is not working:**

```
kaos.indexOf(1, 3)!=-1;
```

or

**this is not working too:**

```
kaos.indexOf(1, 3, 9)!=-1;
```

I want search indexOf(1,3,7, vs), what can I do

Comment: please addd the wanted result as well.

Comment: Basically, you want to search an array inside another array? You want to search the exact sequence or just if `kaos` contains all the value of `zeus` whatever the order?

Comment: I want the result: Is there 1 or 3 digits in the array? true-false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". That's not how [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) works, as a simple search for the documentation would have found.

Comment: Returns true if the number 1 is in the array, false otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and iterate over the wanted item to check if the `kaos` contains an element of `zeus`. The result is an array with boolean values, reflecting the status.

```js
var kaos = [1, 2, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21],
    zeus = [1, 3],
    result = zeus.map(function (value) {
        return kaos.indexOf(value) !== -1;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Real world example.

(I suggest to use arrays instead of strings for keeping data.)

It uses [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which returns `true` only if all checks of the elements returns `true`.

```js
var $scope = { names: [{ prop_Name: 'Location 1', amenities: '1, 3, 5, 8, 11' }, { prop_Name: 'Location 2', amenities: '1, 3, 5, 8, 11' }, { prop_Name: 'Location 3', amenities: '1, 4, 14, 7, 11' }, { prop_Name: 'Location 4', amenities: '17, 3, 25, 8, 11' }, { prop_Name: 'Location 5', amenities: '2, 34, 50, 8, 11' }] },
    amenities = [3, 8],
    result = $scope.names.filter(function (n) {
        return amenities.every(function (a) {
            return n.amenities.split(', ').map(Number).indexOf(a) !== -1;
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: sorry var kaos = [1, 2, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21], zeus = [1, 3] is working but var kaos = [1, 2, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21], zeus = [1, 15] not working.

Comment: What to do to return the result as 0 and -1 ?

Comment: indexOf returns either the index or `-1`. do you like to get `0` and `-1` instead, regardless of the real index?

Comment: this is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/zcgs7yf6/10/ I want indexOf multiple value but not working $scope.am_en = function() { $scope.ot_Filter = function (location) { return location.amenities.indexOf(1)==0; }; } Indexof may be another method filtering : amenities column

Comment: i have no clue, what you want.

Comment: when you check tv button and click submit. (tv button values ​​= 2) angularjs filter find 2 in the amenities column. this is working. but when the TV and CABLE TV check and click submit filter is not working. Because my filter code is bad. $scope.am_en = function()
{
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
return location.amenities.indexOf(1)==0;
};
} how to change this line indexOf(1)

Comment: so you look for `1` and not for `-1`?

Comment: yes i look for it true. i calling input value : var x = $(".hosting_amenities input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(); and try this indexOf(x); this working only one input

Comment: it lokoks, you need another approach, because you need to filter an array by some search values

Comment: So we can not solve it with indexof. What else can we do as a dick? thank you for everything and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: please edit my fiddle page. because I could not integrate

Comment: i have no idea of angular, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

it's also make sure u find the unique ones.

```
 var kaos = [1, 2, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21],
 zeus = [1, 15];
 zeus.every(function (element) {
 if (kaos.indexOf(element) > -1) {
     kaos.splice(kaos.indexOf(element), 1);
       return true;
 };
```